# MySQL: Sort By Verse Number

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to sort by data in Ascending order. Here's how my results are being displayed now:

```
1:1
1:10
1:2
1:3
1:4
1:5
1:6
1:7
1:8
1:9
2:1
```

Instead, I want them like this: `1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:5, 1:6, 1:7, 1:8, 1:9, 1:10, 2:1.`

Currently, my approach is to replace the `:` with a `.`. By adding the `+0` in my query below, I thought it would simply treat my values as integers with decimal places. Any feedback on what I'm missing here?

```
"SELECT myverses.*
FROM myverses
INNER JOIN biblebooks ON myverses.book = biblebooks.name
ORDER BY biblebooks.id ASC, REPLACE(myverses.reference, ':', '.')+0 ASC;";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.2` is the same as `1.20`, which is why it's higher than `1.10`.

You can use:

```
ORDER BY biblebooks.id ASC,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(myverses.reference, ':', 1)*1000 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(myverses.reference, ':', -1) ASC
```

This will convert `1:1` to `1001`, `1.10` to `1010`, `1.2` to `1002`, so they'll sort correctly.

Just make the multiplier larger than the maximum number of verses in a chapter.